# Regex with multiple email address seperated by a semi colon

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build a regex what would allow multiple emails separated with a semicolon for only one domain.

This is what I have now:

`@"^(?>\b[\w+-.%]+@gmail\.com(?:[,;]\s*)?)+\b$"`

This allow 1@gmail.com%2@gmail.com or 1@gmail.com&&2@gmail.com. I just want to have it to be allowed with semicolmn seperator as this. 1@gmail.com;2@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close, just remove the word boundaries, escape the hyphen in the character class and change the last part:

```
^(?>[\w+\-.%]+@gmail\.com(?:;\s*|$))+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XbhCpN/1)

Answer (score 0):

If we are having valid emails, which appears so, and then our cases are limited to those listed in the question, we would be just doing a simple replace on `%` and `&&`, with an expression similar to:

```
(%|&&)|($)
```

If the end of string may not need a `;` then this capturing group might just work, if I understand the problem right:

```
(%|&&)
```

If we would want to validate, then our expression would become slightly complicated to design.

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(%|&&)|($)";
        string substitution = @";";
        string input = @"1@gmail.com%2@gmail.com
1@gmail.com&&2@gmail.com";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/foSFEE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could split your string then use regex for validating the email on each one:

```cs
public string addresses = "1@gmail.com;2@gmail.com";
public List<string> addressList = addresses.Split(";",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
public Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@gmail.com$");

foreach(var email in addressList)
{
     var m = rx.Match(email);

     if(m.Success)
     {
        //Do something with match
     }
}
```

Regex adapted from [.Net General Match](https://emailregex.com/#crayon-5ca92712ae782453819283)